# How to get/dump ssh client effective configuration without connecting

Tags: ssh, configuration

#### Question

Is there an equivalent for `ssh` to `sshd -T` *(or, for those who know, something like maven's `mvn help:effective-pom`)* ?

I'd like to be able to see the effective configuration that will be applied to an `ssh` command without having to / being able to connect to the remote host

#### Context

I've got batches with command line arguments, user local `~/.ssh/config` and global `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` that bring nightmare config extrapolation problems.

Eg. command is failing because global config is forcing the remote port to the wrong ssh daemon / changed the remote username / changed the remote hostname /

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In versions prior openssh-6.8 there is no way except `-Q` option, which is available only for `[-Q cipher | cipher-auth | mac | kex | key]`. You can get only some basic information about parsing ssh config during login with `-v` switch.

In openssh-6.8 and newer, there is switch for ssh, `-G`, which does the same as `-T` for `sshd`:

```bash
ssh -G example.com
```

Comment: I'm still using OpenSSH v5.8 an v6.0 and none support `-G` nor `-Q`. `-v` or `-vvv` doesn't help either because the connexion is refused before interesting data is printed (beside, selected username is never shown)

Comment: no more answer ... I guess I won't have another solution ;) Yours will be the one